# Ubuntu 12.04 on HP ProBook 4530s?

Tags: installation, hybrid-graphics

Has anyone installed correctly Ubuntu 12.04 on HP ProBook 4530s (Radeon HD 6490 M + Intel HD Graphics)?I don't have much time to spend in configurating the system,I would most like to simply install a system that works on my machine.I was tried this 4 months ago but I gave up because of a lot of trouble that I encountered. :(

Comment: Hybrid-graphics/dual-graphics involve some work on Linux and don't always work as well as they do in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I have. 
The battery lasts about an hour and a half.

Video drivers should be installed by generating a ubuntu-specific package from the download from AMD (not by ubuntu's additional drivers).

Hibernation doesn't work (it works, see update).

Everything else works.

**Update**: The only thing I couldn't get to work were additional drivers for the Touchpad on/off led, and its multitouch features.

laptop-tools (package) and indicator-cpufreq increase your battery life, but not by much. I'm still working on that.
https://launchpad.net/indicator-cpufreq

If battery life bothers you, you can read additional information here (there are great links in the answers and comments):
[Ubuntu 12.04 Battery problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163209/ubuntu-12-04-battery-problem)
and 
[Is there ongoing work in the kernel team to improve battery life under linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151884/is-there-ongoing-work-in-the-kernel-team-to-improve-battery-life-under-linux)

indicator-cpufreq PPA (their instruction says not to use for Precise and above, but worked for me):
https://launchpad.net/~artfwo/+archive/ppa

Also, hibernation works (it wasn't enabled by default or something).

To enable hibernation, type:

```
$ gksu gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

And paste the following text into that file:

```
[Enable Hibernate]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Source: [HowtoGeek.com how to enable hibernation in 12.04](http://www.howtogeek.com/113923/how-to-re-enable-hibernate-in-ubuntu-12.04/)